html tools package update to most recent
I am receiving an error when I run install.packages("devtools"). I receive an error message
Warning: package 'devtools' was built under R version 4.3.3.
namespace 'htmltools' 0.5.6.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.7 is required
To resolve, do I need to remove htmltools permanently from the Packages then reinstall
install.packages("htmltools")

No, just install htmltools. You will probably need to restart your session.
